# code igniter, custom selecting data using active record

Tags: activerecord, codeigniter

I want to ask if I need to do this query in my app

```
select qty, type from tItem where qty=0 and (type=1 or price=100)
```

How do I do that using active record in code igniter?

because if i do

```
$this->db->where('qty','0');
$this->db->where('type','1');
$this->db->or_where('price','100');
```

the query would be like

```
select qty, type from tItem where qty=0 and type=1 or price=100
```

and it's not what i meant to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a custom clause, like this:

```
$this->db->where('(type = 1 OR price = 100)');
```